# Locating possible complex solutions to an equation involving a square root

Tags: complex-numbers

Note after reviewing answers. This question illustrates in a non-trivial way how the choice of how to compute the square root in the complex plane can make real difference to the answer you  get.

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/492434/how-to-get-all-solutions-to-equations-with-square-roots/492446?noredirect=1#comment1059730_492446) finding all the solutions came down to solving:

$$ab-1=\sqrt{a^2+b^2+1}$$ subject to $$(a+1)(b+1)=1$$

The condition implies $a^2+b^2+1=(ab-1)^2$, but this leaves open the possibility of $\sqrt {a^2+b^2+1}=1-ab$ rather than $ab-1$.

The solution and discussion on the original question was getting rather long, and dealt mainly with real roots, so I've extracted this sub-question on complex roots.

Could someone please explain what constraints can be put on the complex solutions of this equation - the values of $a$ and $b$ - which would be consistent with the square root operation. It would help if answers were elementary and didn't assume a prior knowledge of complex square roots.

Comment: $a$ and $b$ are complex? If so, it boils down to what you mean by the square root of a complex number. There is no canonical choice.

Comment: @mrf Part of the point of asking for elementary answers is to have that explained, but also to show that a choice can be made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every nonzero complex number $z$ has two "square roots".  You might call one $\sqrt{z}$ and the other $-\sqrt{z}$, but which is which?  A particular choice (for all $z$ in some region of the complex plane) is called a **branch** of the function $\sqrt{z}$.  There is no single branch that is continuous everywhere: if you start at some point with a particular choice of $\sqrt{z}$ and travel in a loop around $0$, keeping $\sqrt{z}$ continuous along your path, when you come back to the start $\sqrt{z}$ will have $-$ its original value.  A curve $\Gamma$ in whose complement your branch is continuous is called a **branch cut**.

One popular choice, called the "principal branch", is to make the real part of $\sqrt{z}$ always $\ge 0$.  The branch cut in this case is the negative real axis.

Comment: Note that using this particular branch cut with the real part of the square root always $\ge 0$ implies that we have a consistent solution provided the real part of $ab-1$ is greater than zero.

Answer (score 1):

Let's pursue Robert Israel's line of thinking, and take $a$ as the complex number $x+iy$, with $b=-\frac a{a+1}$.

We define the principal value of the square root of a complex number as having non-negative real part, with the square root of a negative real number being a value on the positive imaginary axis (when the real part is zero)

Then the condition for $(a,b)$ to be a solution is that $ab-1$ has positive real part, or lies on the positive imaginary axis. This guarantees that it is in the half-plane which contains the square root we are looking for. The alternative possibility lies in the other half plane.

Now $$ab-1=-\frac{a^2}{a+1}-1=-\frac {a^2+a+1}{a+1}=-a-\frac 1{a+1}$$$$=-x-iy-\frac1{(x+1)+iy}=-x-iy-\frac{x+1-iy}{(x+1)^2+y^2}$$

Now take the real part $$-\frac {x((x+1)^2+y^2)+(x+1)}{(x+1)^2+y^2}$$ We are interested only in the sign, and the denominator is always positive, so our condition becomes $$-(x((x+1)^2+y^2)+(x+1))\gt 0$$ or removing the minus sign $$x((x+1)^2+y^2)+(x+1)\lt 0$$.

Clearly this implies $x\lt 0$ (otherwise both terms are non-negative, and there is no case of equality). If $x\lt -1$ both terms on the left-hand side are negative, and the equation is satisfied whatever $y$ is.

If $x=-1$ then the only condition is easily seen to be that $y$ is non-zero. If $x=-1, y=0$ the basic condition is not satisfied, so there is no solution.

In the case $-1\lt x \lt 0$ we note that $x+1\gt 0$ and $$xy^2\lt-x(x+1)^2-(x+1)$$ $x$ is negative, so when we divide by $x$ we reverse the inequality$$y^2\gt-(x+1)^2-1-\frac 1x$$

Answer (score 1):

An alternative choice for the square root is in the upper half plane - with positive imaginary part, and including the non-negative real line where the imaginary part is zero. (see my other answer where I took Robert Israel's suggestion of the right half plane, positive real part). This answer is to illustrate that the choice matters.

We still have$$ab-1=-\frac{a^2}{a+1}-1=-\frac {a^2+a+1}{a+1}=-a-\frac 1{a+1}$$$$=-x-iy-\frac1{(x+1)+iy}=-x-iy-\frac{x+1-iy}{(x+1)^2+y^2}$$

But now we take the imaginary part $$-y-\frac {y}{(x+1)^2+y^2}=-\frac{y(x+1)^2+y^3+y}{(x+1)^2+y^2}$$

Again the denominator is positive, so we want to control the sign of the numerator by ensuring $$y((x+1)^2+y^2+1)\lt 0$$

This is $y$ times a term which is easily seen to be positive, so the condition is $y\lt0$

The case with $y=0$ is the real case, which is excluded in the question because it has been analysed separately.

Note that this choice of  branch cut (along the positive real axis) leads to a much simpler condition than the more standard alternative. So this is a nice illustration of how even simple definitions can make a significant difference.

Answer (score 0):

a²+b²+1 = (ab-1)²,
a²+b²+1=a²b²-2ab+1,
(a+b)²=a²b²,
So a+b = ab or a+b = -ab ,

Second constraint.

(a+1)(b+1)=1, 
ab+a+b=0

eliminate a+b gives either 0=0 (true statement all a,b) or 2ab=0 implying a = 0 or b = 0
From your original problem, is their a possibility perhaps that either a = 0 or b = 0 ???

Answer (score 0):

(A solution using too much algebra.)

I show that
the solutions are
$a=0, b=0$
and
$a=1, b=-1/2$
and,
in both of these,
the minus sign has to be taken
in the $\sqrt{}$.

If
$(a+1)(b+1)=1$,
then
$b = \dfrac1{a+1}-1$
so

$\begin{align}
ab-1
&=a(\frac1{a+1}-1)-1\\
&=a\frac1{a+1}-(a+1)\\
&=\frac{a-(a+1)^2}{a+1}\\
&=\frac{-a^2-a-1}{a+1}\\
&=-\frac{a^2+a+1}{a+1}\\
\end{align}
$

and

$\begin{align}
a^2+b^2+1
&=a^2+(\frac1{a+1}-1)^2+1\\
&=a^2+(\frac1{a+1})^2-2\frac1{a+1}+2\\
&=\frac{a^2(a+1)^2+1-2(a+1)+2(a+1)^2}{(a+1)^2}\\
&=\frac{(a^2+2)(a+1)^2+1-2(a+1)}{(a+1)^2}\\
&=\frac{(a^2+2)(a^2+2a+1)-2a-1}{(a+1)^2}\\
&=\frac{a^4+2a^3+a+2a^2+4a+2-2a-1}{(a+1)^2}\\
&=\frac{a^4+2a^3+2a^2+3a+1}{(a+1)^2}\\
\end{align}
$

Putting these in 
$ab-1=\sqrt{a^2+b^2+1}
$,

$-\dfrac{a^2+a+1}{a+1}
=\sqrt{\dfrac{a^4+2a^3+2a^2+3a+1}{(a+1)^2}}
$.

Multiplying both sides by
$a+1$,
$-(a^2+a+1)
=\sqrt{a^4+2a^3+2a^2+3a+1}
$.

Since
$(a^2+a+1)^2
=a^4+2a^3+3a^2+2a+1
$,
squaring and subtracting gives
$3a^2+2a = 2a^2+3a$
or
$a^2 = a$,
so
$a=0$
or $a=1$.

If $a=0$,
then $b=0$
and we have to take
the negative sign in the $\sqrt{}$.

If $a=1$,
then $b=-1/2$,
$ab-1 = -3/2$,
and
$a^2+b^2+1
=1+1/4+1
=9/4
= (3/2)^2
$,
and,
again,
we have to take
the negative sign in the $\sqrt{}$.